# What to set as APP URL in Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, github, ip

I'm a newbie to Laravel Homestead and I am just wondering what should I set as the APP URL in my project .env file?

It currently has localhost but I want to connect a domain I got to it so would I be able to have the APP URL as my domain name or does it have to be something like an IP address? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`APP_URL` should be whatever URL you're viewing in the browser as you develop. e.g. `APP_URL=https://localhost`. Your `.env` file should never be committed to git, and should be specific to your environment. You should have one `.env` for development, and a different one for your production (on your live server). The `.env` file on your live server should use the domain you own instead `APP_URL=https://myawesomedomain.com`.